# ant: the generated JAR cannot be executed

Tags: java, ant, jar, javac

I've written/copied a simple ant example and am trying to deploy a Java progamm with it. My build file `bsp0201.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project name="bsp0201" default="main" basedir=".">
    <property name="dir.src" value="./source" />
    <property name="dir.build" value="./classes" />
    <property name="dir.lib" value="./lib" />
    <path id="cp">
        <pathelement path="${classpath}" />
        <pathelement location="${dir.build}" />
    </path>
    <target name="main" depends="prepare, compile, run" />
    <target name="prepare">
        <mkdir dir="${dir.build}" />
        <delete>
            <fileset dir="${dir.build}" includes="**/*" />
        </delete>
    </target>
    <target name="compile">
        <javac classpathref="cp" destdir="${dir.build}" srcdir="${dir.src}" includes="**/*.java" includeantruntime="false" />
        <mkdir dir="${dir.lib}" />
        <jar destfile="${dir.lib}/ae.jar">
            <fileset dir="${dir.build}" includes="**/*.class" />
        </jar>
    </target>
    <target name="run" if="test">
        <java classname="main.GeoAnalyzerMain" classpath="${dir.lib}/ae.jar">
            <arg line="${test}" />
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

My ant commando & the result output:

```
# ant -f bsp0201.xml run -Dtest=Echo
Buildfile: /var/www/sandbox/ant/bsp0201/bsp0201.xml

run:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Ant generates the folders, the class files and a JAR file `ae.jar`. But the size of this JAR file is only 19.1 KB (instead of 297 KB of the JAR file, when I generate it with eclipse) and I cannot execute it. What do I do wrong?

Thx

Comment: The build says it's successful, so the program has been executed. Look at the contents of both jar files and see if there's a difference. Maybe it's just the compression level that is different.

Comment: Are all the source code files in the `./source` directory? After running the build, does the `./classes` directory contain all the compiled classes?

Comment: You can use jar -tvf to list the contents of jar files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the build XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project name="bsp0201" default="main" basedir=".">
    <property name="dir.src" value="./source" />
    <property name="dir.build" value="./classes" />
    <property name="dir.lib" value="./lib" />
    <path id="cp">
        <pathelement path="${classpath}" />
        <pathelement location="${dir.build}" />
    </path>
    <target name="main" depends="prepare, compile, run" />
    <target name="prepare">
        <mkdir dir="${dir.build}" />
        <delete>
            <fileset dir="${dir.build}" includes="**/*" />
        </delete>
    </target>
    <target name="compile">
        <javac classpathref="cp" destdir="${dir.build}" srcdir="${dir.src}" includes="**/*.java" includeantruntime="false" />
        <mkdir dir="${dir.lib}" />
        <jar destfile="${dir.lib}/AntExample.jar">
            <fileset dir="${dir.build}" includes="**/*.class" />
            <fileset dir=".">
                <include name="img/*.*" />
            </fileset>
        </jar>
    </target>
    <target name="run" if="test">
        <java classname="main.GeoAnalyzerMain" classpath="${dir.lib}/AntExample.jar">
            <arg line="${test}" />
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

Now the image folder is copied into the result archive. But the JAR still cannot be executed.

EDIT:

It works!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project name="bsp0201" default="main" basedir=".">
    <property name="dir.src" value="./source" />
    <property name="dir.build" value="./classes" />
    <property name="dir.lib" value="./lib" />
    <path id="cp">
        <pathelement path="${classpath}" />
        <pathelement location="${dir.build}" />
    </path>
    <target name="main" depends="prepare, compile, run" />
    <target name="prepare">
        <mkdir dir="${dir.build}" />
        <delete>
            <fileset dir="${dir.build}" includes="**/*" />
        </delete>
    </target>
    <target name="compile">
        <javac classpathref="cp" destdir="${dir.build}" srcdir="${dir.src}" includes="**/*.java" includeantruntime="false" />
        <mkdir dir="${dir.lib}" />
        <jar destfile="${dir.lib}/AntExample.jar">
            <fileset dir="${dir.build}" includes="**/*.class" />
            <fileset dir=".">
                <include name="img/*.*" />
            </fileset>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="main.GeoAnalyzerMain" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
    <target name="run" if="test">
        <java classname="main.GeoAnalyzerMain" classpath="${dir.lib}/AntExample.jar">
            <arg line="${test}" />
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, was a good idea to compare the JARs. :) Here you can see the comparsion result:

[image: JARs comparison]

The folder /img and the /.classpath are missing in the Ant-JAR. Why has Ant not included them? How can I make Ant to include the missing files/folders?

Comment: `.classpath` and `.project` are internal `Eclipse IDE` settings file. It should not have any affect on running the binary java code. They are hidden files (in UNIX) and ANT would probably skip them, by default, when creating a jar file.